# Summary of the permissions of the various files and directories for an Apache + Python web server

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I have been wrestling with my Digital Ocean + Ubuntu + Apache 2.4 + mod_wsgi + Python 3.11 + Flask server for days at this point trying to get my web app running, and it has been a nightmare for me to try to wrap my head around which Ubuntu user should be the owner of which files and what the permissions should be, and which user should be running various commands.

I wish there was a simple summary I could refer to.

My understanding is that there should be at least three Ubuntu users on the server:

- `root` - This user account should be used to install system-wide software.
- `www-data` - This is the user account that Apache will generally run as, and it needs permission to access the app directory (and other directories?).
- `my-dev-user` - This is my personal non-root user account which I'll use day-to-day when I SSH into the server, and with which I'll do everything that I don't need to use `sudo` for.  So, like, in my case this user would be named `nathan`.
- `github-user` - Should there be a shared Ubuntu user to pull code from GitHub if there are multiple developers?  Like, I don't understand how I'm supposed to set up the git remote URL if multiple different devs need to be pulling from GitHub.

Below is my current understanding of the software that needs to be installed and the directories and files that need to be managed; I'd like to have an easy-to-reference summary that lists--for each of these installations and directories and files--which user should be used to create / own them and whether any nonstandard permissions should be set.

- Apache - Installed with `sudo`?

  - `/etc/apache2/` and its subdirectories.
  - The app config at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<app-name>.conf`
- mod_wsgi - Installed with `sudo`?

  - `/etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load`
- Global Python installation - Installed with `sudo`?

  - `/usr/bin/python`
  - `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/`

    - Replace 'X.Y' with whatever version of Python you've installed.
- App-specific Python virtual environment - Created with `my-dev-user`?

  - `/usr/local/venvs/<your-app-venv>/`
- App repo / project directory - Created with `my-dev-user`?

  - `/var/www/<app-name>`
  - To pull the project `git init` needs to be run; as `my-dev-user`?
  - `git pull` - Run as `my-dev-user`?  Or `github-user`?
- App WSGI file - Created with `my-dev-user`?

  - Let's say it's at `/var/www/<app-name>/backend/wsgi/`
- The SSH config and keys used to pull the app's code from GitHub:

  - `/home/github-user/.ssh/config`
  - `/home/github-user/.ssh/<ssh-key-for-the-app>`

Feel free to add to the list of directories / files / installations if I missed something.  I'm hoping someone will use the above as a template for their answer.